Quote identification: Schindler war ein kleiner Rabe
John Rabe is known for his humanitarian actions during the Nanjing massacre, cf. link to the German Wikipedia.
I remember well, but might be mistaken, that in one version of the very same German Wikipedia page in 2019/20, roughly, there was a quote by Chinese scholars written in German translation in the following context:
Chinese scholars/historians speculated that Schindler, in contrast to Rabe in saving Chinese civilians, was guided in saving Jews during the Holocaust by declaring them as indispensible workers not only by humanitarian intentions but also economical. There was a reference in the German Wikipedia to one of their publications in a learned journal where they concluded; the German translation of a originally probably Chinese quote of the once German Wikipedia follows with an English translation:

Schindler war ein kleiner Rabe.


Schindler was a little Rabe.

I checked the version history of the German Wikipedia page and searched online but was unable to locate this quotation anymore. I am interested mostly in the Chinese original together with a reference to its source.
(This question is both a fit for Chinese Language Stackexchange and Literature Stackexchange but I opted for this page because it has the tag "quote source".)
(In English, we have the words "small" and "little" to describe a person and I don't know which one does not refer to a person's height but to his grandeur. You might correct me. In Chinese, however, the appropriate word in this context is almost for sure 小. For the German version, I am sure that the word "klein" was used and it is the only appropriate.)

The only source I can find is this post
Basically the post (a news report by Taiwan's official news agency) says a Chinese writer Iris Shun-Ru Chang called Rabe as "China's Schindler" in her book The Rape of Nanking: The Forgotten Holocaust of World War, and Ma Yingjiu, the president of Taiwan at that time (2015), said he disagreed with Chang and he thought "Schindler was a little Rabe" because Schindler only protected around 1000 people, while Rabe saved around 250 thousand. I'm not sure if that's the very original source, though.

Nitpick: Iris Chang was an American author and journalist of Chinese descent.

On p. 109 of Iris Chang, The Rape of Nanking: 'In 1996 I began an investigation into the life of John Rabe and eventually unearthed thousands of pages of diaries that he and other Nazis kept during the Rape. These diaries led me to conclude that John Rabe was "the Oskar Schindler of China."'
